# Where Can I find the detailed API for Uber Eats?

Tags: api, uber-api

I could find the API for Uber Rush in https://developer.uber.com,  but not for Uber EATS, where would this information lie?

Comment: did you find any updated info on intergrating uber eats since you asked this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not currently a publicly available API for UberEATS. Any news on that front would be announced on the [Uber API developers blog](https://medium.com/uber-developers).

Also, for non-technical or non-coding questions like these about Uber's API, it might be better to follow up with them directly on their [community forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/uber-developers), rather than on StackOverflow. Thanks!

Comment: I found this: https://developer.uber.com/docs/eats/