# Is there any way to connect with Uber Eats?

Tags: uber-api

I [found a 2017 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382449/where-can-i-find-the-detailed-api-for-uber-eats) about integrating with the Uber Eats API, which said there was no public API for it. Since then, is there anything new about integrating with Uber Eats? Is there any way in Uber's own API to get data related to the Uber Eats application?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where Can I find the detailed API for Uber Eats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382449/where-can-i-find-the-detailed-api-for-uber-eats)

Comment: The accepted answer of the duplicate link refers you to the Uber API developers' blog.  Did you try looking at that?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I checked the recent posts, but I did not find anything new about this integration with Uber Eats. With this, I tried to find out if the Uber API itself is able to get related data from Uber Eats, but I also did not find anything about it.

Comment: Then there most likely is not anything new, assuming that SO also has nothing to say about it.  Sit back and wait, and maybe try using Seamless (if in USA) or Grab Food (if in Asia).

Comment: Thanks a lot, @TimBiegeleisen. I have this doubt of integration with UberEats for having seen the OrderOut site (https://orderout.co/), which connects to UberEats and other applications in its solution. However, researching on it really could not find any source of how to effect an integration similar to what OrderOut does.

Comment: Maybe Uber Eats opens their API to close third party partners/vendors.  This does not mean that they would open that API to the general public though.

Comment: There is no public UberEATS API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Uber hasn't released a public **API** for it... There are alternatives to do so.

1. Sending Activity request to the uber eats application and wait for the Activities result. For which the documentation is given below,.
   [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing)
2. You can launch an instance of the application using instant app.